# Why can you call foo() and &foo before the declaration of sub foo, but you can't call plain foo?

Tags: perl

Please explain why the way these Perl functions are called *above the definition of the function* determines whether they run or not.

```
print "Why does this bare call to foo not run?\n";
foo;
print "When this call to foo() does run?\n";
foo();
print "And this call to &foo also runs?\n";
&foo;

sub foo {
    print "    print from inside function foo:\n";
}

print "And this bare call to foo below the function definition, does run?\n";
foo;
```

Answer (score 7):

You can only omit parentheses in a function call if the parser knows the identifier in question refers to a function.

Your first `foo;` is not a function call because the parser hasn't seen `sub foo` yet (and `foo` is not a builtin).

If you'd used `use strict; use warnings;` at the top, this would have been flagged as an error.

Answer (score 3):

Quote [perldata](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html),

> A word that has no other interpretation in the grammar will be treated as if it were a quoted string. These are known as "barewords".

That means that `foo` is equivalent to `"foo"` absent a sub declaration giving it an alternate interpretation.

```
$ perl -e'my $x = foo; print("$x\n");'
foo
```

This is considered a mis-feature, so it is disabled by `use strict;` (or more specifically, by `use strict qw( subs );`) in order to catch typos.

```
$ perl -e'use strict; my $x = foo; print("$x\n");'
Bareword "foo" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at -e line 1.
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.
```

Always use `use strict; use warnings qw( all );`!